# The Flutter.framework Source Code Could not debug?

Tags: flutter

I wanna use my customized flutter complied flutter.framework to replace the original one.but after compling the source code according the tutorial:https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Compiling-the-engine. And replace the flutter.framework in my  project.Then I can debug into the source code.But the debug point that i setted did not work well.it did not move step by step.
[the debug point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUCe9.jpg)

Comment: For breakpoints to work in Flutter from your project, you have to enable a flag. I don't know where to do it in InteliJ, but that's how we do it with vscode

Comment: @RémiRousselet  i debug  in the Xcode